# XSL external link to docbook.xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, sed, docbook

Very often I run across some documentation which is to be produced for various viewing formats by a makefile calling a XML/XSLT processor. Many times the stylesheets themselves access the standard docbook.xsl per the usual URI. Bad thing if you are without connection. I worked around this the last time by finally learning some sed/grep/xargs (ok, one should know that much anyway) and pointing to a local docbook.xsl (they are quite abundant on every system I came across for the last years) but I think it is really unsatisfying, given the verbose nature of XML that there is no better or standard fallback mechanism for this problem. Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supported by your XML parser, using catalogs can help, see http://xmlsoft.org/catalog.html for xsltproc/libxslt.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The explanation there is much more readable than the W3C text :D